# get only final value from angular queryParams

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-routing

My goal is to find out if the query param `project` is set at loading of the application. Whilst I also have to load a list of projects. When I got both informations I can proceed with my logic.

Here is what I got so far

```
combineLatest([
  this.route.queryParams.pipe(pluck('project')),
  this.projects$.pipe(first(),filter(p => p && p.length > 0))
]).subscribe(([projectParam, projects]) => {
  console.log(projectParam, projects);
});
```

The `this.route`is of type ActivatedRoute: https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute

The projects$ observable works ideally. But the queryParams observable is being called twice. Once with the value `undefined` and then later on with the real value. But I just want the last value. 
Since the url is optional both options are valid.

Any idea how I can make queryParams just fire on the final value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the discussion here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12157
I came up with the following solution:

```
private get finalQueryParams$(): Observable<Params> {
  return merge(
    // get urls with query params like /test?project=test
    this.route.queryParams.pipe(
      filter(params => Object.keys(params).length > 0)
    ),
    // get urls without query params like /test
    this.route.queryParams.pipe(
      filter(() => !(window.location.href || '').includes('?')),
      map(() => ({}))
    )
  );
}
```

It fires just once and I get the real value of the queryParams.

In the code above I then just had to change it to

```
combineLatest([
  this.finalQueryParams$.pipe(pluck('project')),
  this.projects$.pipe(first(),filter(p => p && p.length > 0))
]).subscribe(([projectParam, projects]) => {
  console.log(projectParam, projects);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using last rxjs operator

```
this.route.queryParams.pipe(last(), pluck('project'))
```

Comment: this doesn't work. the code in subscribe is never called. I put this into ngOnInit:     `this.route.queryParams
      .pipe(last(), pluck('project'))
      .subscribe((project) => console.log(project));`

Answer (score 0):

`this.route.queryParams` is internally implemented as a Subject that never completes but you want it to complete right after the first value different than `undefined`.

So you can use for example `takeWhile` with optional second argument:

```
this.route.queryParams.pipe(
  takeWhile(val => val === undefined, true), // or maybe !Boolean(val)
  takeLast(1),
  pluck('project')),
)
```

Or maybe it'd would be easier to use just `filter()` amd `take(1)`.

Comment: yes something like that can work if I want project to be a required value, but if there is no project in the query params, then this will never complete

Comment: So what do you want to do? Wait until `queryParams` emits a non-undefined value or take the first value whatever it is?

Comment: if there is a `project` parameter in the url, then I want the value of it, otherwise ùndefined`

Answer (score 0):

You can use skip operator to **skip** the first one.

```
 combineLatest([
      this.route.queryParams.pipe(pluck('project')),
      this.projects$.pipe(first(),filter(p => p && p.length > 0))
    ]).pipe(skip(1)).subscribe(([projectParam, projects]) => {
      console.log(projectParam, projects);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you can't simply subscribe `route.queryParams` and check is it have `project` parameter.

Here is my idea of doing your task.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams => {
        if (queryParams.project) {
            // proceed with your logic
        }
    });
}
```